# Unable to save to HttpRuntime.Cache while in an async Task

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am modifying some code to do XYZ and such and am running into an issue.

WebAPI method

```
public async Task<FileUploadResult> PostFile([FromUri]int width)
{
    // Right here the HTTPContext.Current == null;
    ... Some code here
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
}
```

I have looked and seen that this line will restore your HttpContext.Current

```
add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"
```

So I have added the above setting and it returns the HttpContext.Current.
From what I can tell I can access (read) the .Cache object from both HttpContext.Current.Cache and HttpRuntime.Cache.

but, for some reason I cannot write to the cache, successfully anyways.

My code does not throw an exception, but when I try to read the cache it simply not there.

My code works very well everywhere else, just not inside an async web api call.

Cache Code

```
private Cache sysCache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
// also treid  private Cache sysCache = HttpRuntime.Cache
sysCache.Insert(fileToCache.ToMD5HashString(), 
                        fileToCache,
                        null,
                        Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                        new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0));
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you enter async you lose the current context (which includes HttpContext.Current). Try passing the current HttpContext as an argument.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work.  Something else is at play here that will not let me store to the cache.  Even if I am able to access the cache (read) using you suggestion or key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" the items being stored to cache just arent saving.

Comment: That's odd because the documentation states that "There is one instance of the Cache class per application domain. As a result, the Cache object that is returned by the Cache property is the Cache object for all requests in the application domain."

Comment: Have you checked if the item is there after inserting? Have you tried `HttpRuntime.Cache` instead?

Comment: Yes I have tried HttpRuntime and it appears that the results are the same.  Something to note - When calling cache from the secondary thread the cache is empty (0 items stored), when calling from the main thread the cache has about 50 items stored.  So when I Insert the item into cache (secondary thread), yes, the results do show the items I have just inserted, they are the only items in the cache at that moment. But when I check the cache on the main thread they are not there.

Comment: I expected the same behavior, but expected it to work. `HttpContext.Cache' instance property returns the value of `HttpRuntime.Cache`static property. But it's a bad practice to use anything ASP.NET related out of the "main" thread because situations like this may occurr.

Comment: Thank you very much for you assistance.  It turned out to not have to do with the async runtime at all. As it turns out, my class that was storing items into cache, and the web api that was trying to call the items were in two different applications existing under the same site, so they had two different cache stores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much for you assistance. It turned out to not have to do with the async runtime at all. As it turns out, my class that was storing items into cache, and the web api that was trying to call the items were in two different applications existing under the same site, so they had two different cache stores.